# What exception should I throw when method returns invalid result

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I want to know what exception(is there any in .NET) should I throw when called method returns unexpected result.

For example, imagine situation where I have factory:

```
public abstract class Factory
{
    public A Create()
    {
        var a = new A();
        var b = CreateDependencyOfA();
        a.Something = b.Property;
    }

    protected abstract B CreateDependencyOfA();
}
```

I document that class and create assumption that CreateDependencyOfA does not return null(or anything else, i.e. for integer assuming that value is between 1 and 5).

What should I do when implementation breaks this contract (returning in this case null). Is there in .NET any exception type designed for this purpose? I know there are some ArgumentExceptions but they, from what I know, for input parameters . Is there equivalent for output parameters?

I am asking this because I believe there is some kind of symmetry between input and output parameters but I do not know any exceptions for output.

Comment: You are always able to create your own `Exception`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a method returns a value that it should never return, it means that there is an internal logic error in your program. Errors of this kind (i.e. situations that must never happen if the code is designed to specification) are best handled by [assertions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e63efys0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var dependency = Factory.CreateDependencyOfA();
Debug.Assert(dependency != null, "Factory returned null dependency.");
```

Note: use of assertions assumes that you are checking the output of your own method. In other words, you own the `Factory` and all its implementations, that you wrote all the `CreateDependencyOfA` methods, and that you know that these methods must not return `null`.

If an implementation of the `Factory` is a plug-in written by somebody else, you should not use an assertion. Instead, use [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to indicate that the current state (namely, the `Factory` implementation supplied to you) is invalid.

Comment: Are you sure InvalidOperationException is correct type to throw in such case? From MSDN "The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.". In my opinion object state is valid when calling method. Problem comes with that method's result. I mean, I would throw InvalidOperationException in kitchen.openFridge() when there is no fridge inside that kitchen.

Comment: @knopo One could argue that the subclass of `Factory` configured for your system's use is part of your program's state. In other words, it's the `Factory` that's invalid, not the return of its `CreateDependencyOfA` method.

Comment: This is not true.  There are many scenarios where an invalid result may occur.  I can easily name 1: An expected item is not found in a collection.  In a case such as this it is perfectly valid to create a KeyNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out Code Contracts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx

For example, your CreateDependencyOfA method might include a contract such as:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<B>() != null);
```