# Appropriate exception when a callback returns an illegal value?

Tags: java, validation, exception, callback

Does the JDK include an exception-type that it would be appropriate to throw if a callback returns an illegal value (or otherwise behaves unexpectedly)?

For example, consider a class that takes a supplier as a constructor argument, and invokes it both during and after the constructor call:

```
public class Example {
    private Object fField;
    private Supplier<Object> fFieldValueSupplier;

    public Example(final Supplier<Object> fieldValueSupplier) {
        fFieldValueSupplier = fieldValueSupplier;
        updateField();
    }

    public final void updateField() {
        fField = fFieldValueSupplier.get();
    }

    // ... other stuff ...
}
```

Ideally `updateField()` should do whatever validation is appropriate before actually using the result of `fFieldValueSupplier.get()`, but — what should it throw if the result is in fact invalid? In a simple `setField(Object)`, I'd usually raise `IllegalArgumentException` if the argument were invalid; but that doesn't seem appropriate in this case, since the "invalid argument" is really the constructor argument, and the constructor may have already completed. Is there another predefined exception type that is more appropriate?

(I've tried to think of JDK classes where this might come up, so I can see how they handle it; but I can't find any good analogue. The closest I can find is `Collections.sort`, which can-but-need-not raise `IllegalArgumentException` if the list-element comparisons aren't conforming to the contract of `Comparable.compareTo` / `Comparator.compare`. I was hoping that `TreeSet` would provide a good example, since it depends on the same sort of thing but in a constructor argument; but its documentation doesn't seem to mention the issue.)

Comment: Does anything speaks against creating your own exception?

Comment: the base problem is that there should be no work in the constructor (http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/), then this problem would not exist

Comment: @EmersonCod: Feel free to ignore the "work" in the constructor, if you prefer. Despite what you claim, the problem exists with or without it.

Comment: @Clayn: Not really. But I think it's better to use standard exceptions, when they do exist, since their meaning is clear and well-known. (I'd be annoyed if I had to deal with code that had its own `NullReferenceException` and `InvalidArgumentException` and `OutOfBoundsArrayIndexException` instead of using the similar JDK classes.)

Comment: @EmersonCod: (By the way, if you read the page that you link to, you'll see that this is not what it's complaining about.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exception should I throw when method returns invalid result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170310/what-exception-should-i-throw-when-method-returns-invalid-result)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus: Thanks for the link! But that question is about C# / .Net, whereas this one is about Java / JDK. Additionally, the accepted answer there assumes a different relationship between the misbehaving method and the method detecting the misbehavior. As a result, it's not applicable to this question.

Comment: I retracted that. I don't know why it's still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the JDK include an exception-type that would be appropriate to throw an instance of if a callback returns an illegal value?

No, but let's examine some plausible candidates to be sure:

- `IllegalArgumentException`: a return value is not an argument.
- `IllegalStateException`: sounds like it might be appropriate, but demands that the problem exists because the method was **invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time**. However, timing isn't *necessarily* the issue given the question. The nuance here is with whether you can be sure who it is you are trying to complain about with this exception.
- `UnsupportedOperationException`: suggests that the illegal operation *could* be legal (and supported) in a different implementation of the interface you are implementing, but you aren't implementing an interface.

**What you need to do comes down to what you want your API contract to be.**

### Exhibit A: Constructor specifies that argument must be valid

If your constructor specifies that `fieldValueSupplier` **must** be valid (i.e. it never supplies us with an invalid object) then your options are:

1. throwing a custom exception deriving from `RuntimeException`.
2. throwing a `RuntimeException`.
3. engaging in undefined behavior.

You generally should choose (1): if nothing else, it improves testability. You should choose (2) if you really, really dislike how non-DRY (1) tends to make your code look; this admittedly is an issue stemming from the language specification, but you should be careful of letting the extra mile influence your decision making. You should choose (3) if the affected code is on a hot path and excessive checking causes an unacceptable performance impact. This is rare because of branch prediction, and the unfortunate developer will thank you for not choosing this option whenever possible.

The reason that the default library is so sparsely equipped with reusable exception types comes down to what the benefits of exception types are in the first place:

1. the caller can decide which problems to deal with at which point in their code.
2. developers can understand the cause of a problem faster when they read the exception's type name in the stack trace **and** are familiar with it.

If we use a standard library exception type, we don't get (1) because we cannot be certain what the origin of the exception is. If we create our own exception type, we don't get (2) because no one has ever seen it before. If there was a niche exception type in the standard library and we used it, we would get neither (1) nor (2).

### Exhibit B: Constructor does not specify that argument must be valid

If your constructor does **not** specify that `fieldValueSupplier` must be valid, your only option becomes to throw a custom exception deriving from `Exception`, i.e. throwing a checked exception. Everything else would admit to the caller that your API is of poor quality, since you make no explanation as to what happens when an invalid input is provided, not even that it leads to undefined behavior (which, technically, *is* a definition of what happens).

Whether you throw a checked or an unchecked exception is entirely within your power to decide. Unchecked exceptions hint at programming errors, but they don't tell you where the programming error is, or who made the programming error, so you want to throw them as far upwards in the call stack as possible as to not make the developer think the problem is in your code. (Unless it is, of course, in the case of which: go fix your code.)

> ```java
> public class Example {
>     private Object fField;
>     private Supplier<Object> fFieldValueSupplier;
>
>     public Example(final Supplier<Object> fieldValueSupplier) {
>         fFieldValueSupplier = fieldValueSupplier;
>         updateField();
>     }
>
>     public final void updateField() {
>         fField = fFieldValueSupplier.get();
>     }
>
>     // ... other stuff ...
> }
> ```

In this case, you would want to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` from the constructor, since you *do* have an opportunity to check the first value you get right then and there. In `updateField()`, you could throw an `IllegalStateException`: the method is public and you do not call it yourself, so the problem exists because the caller called it at a *time* when `fFieldValueSupplier` would supply an invalid object. (Notice why this is different from what I said about `IllegalStateException` earlier: we're clearly complaining about an outside force here, i.e. we are making the decision to rule out that this check is a sanity-check against bugs in our own code)

However, you would really want to throw an exception of your own type which derives from `IllegalStateException`. The reason is that `fieldValueSupplier` is not only not controlled by your class (or package), but it may also not be controlled by the caller, either: unless the argument is immutable, there is no telling which code on the caller's side is at fault when this exception is thrown!

```java
public class Example {
    private Object fField;
    private Supplier<Object> fFieldValueSupplier;

    public Example(final Supplier<Object> fieldValueSupplier) {
        if (fieldValueSupplier == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("fieldValueSupplier must not be null.");
        }
        fFieldValueSupplier = fieldValueSupplier;
        updateField(fFieldValueSupplier.get());
    }

    private final void updateField(Object field) {
        if (!isValid(field)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("fieldValueSupplier must not supply an invalid field.")
        }
    }

    public final void updateField() {
        fField = fFieldValueSupplier.get();
        if (!isValid(fField)) {
            throw new SupplierInvalidatedException("received invalid value from fieldValueSupplier.");
        }
        updateField(fField);
    }

    // ... other stuff ...
}
```

### From insight to wisdom

Good principles are worth a lot, but doing everything out of principle is worthless. Instead of thinking "what should I throw here?", ask "what would I like the stack trace to look like if this happens?". The answer to this question shouldn't change depending on things outside of your code, but it will. As you see who pays the price for poor code, and who fails to benefit from good code, you can adjust things accordingly.